# Unresolved external symbol. Definition ok

Tags: c++

I know this problem may occur when I declare function and not define it. 
But this is not the case.

```
//In the 'H' file. Template class.
BSNode(T data);


\\In the cpp definitions

template <class T>
BSNode<T>::BSNode(T data)
{
    _root = this;
    _data = data;
    _right = NULL;
    _left = NULL;
}
```

And still, I get the next Error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BSNode<int>::BSNode<int>(int)" (??0?$BSNode@H@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in function _main  c:\Users\a\OneDrive\ss\visual studio 2013\Projects\Project5\2\Source.obj    2_TREES
```

What also may cause this Error to occur if its not the incompatibility between the 'H' and the 'cpp' files?

Answer (score 0):

The code that uses this constructor with the `int` instantiation should also be in the `.cpp` file. The compiler needs it to generate the instance of the code, because it cannot generate all possible instances.

Several solutions:

- move at least one use of the constructor with the `int` instance in the `cpp` file
- rename the `.cpp` file into a `.template` file that you can include in every file that uses the `BSNode` instances.
- add `template class BSNode<int>;` in the `.cpp` file to force the template instantiation.